# in pyspark i am reading json file , i want to create a dataframe , in which one of the column contains keys as values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

**I am reading json file in pyspark, i have to make keys as one of the column values, can you please help in this , below is sample file**

```
{
  "Premiums": {
    "ACCOUNT": [
      "1001",
      "1002"
    ]
  },
  "Claims": {
    "ACCOUNT": [
      "2001",
      "2002"
    ]
  },
  "Expenses Acquisition": {
    "ACCOUNT": [
      "3001",
      "3002"
    ],
    "KEY_FIGURE": [
      "3400530",
      "910050505"
    ]
  },
  "Expenses Run-Off": {
    "ACCOUNT": [
      "3001",
      "3002"
    ],
    "KEY_FIGURE": [
      "3400535",
      "910100505"
    ]
  }
}
```

**i want output as below**

```
+--------------------+------------+--------------------+
|measurements        |ACCOUNT     |KEY_FIGURE          |
+--------------------+------------+--------------------+
|Claims              |[2001, 2002]|null                |
|Expenses Acquisition|[3001, 3002]|[3400530, 910050505]|
|Expenses Run-Off    |[3001, 3002]|[3400535, 910100505]|
|Premiums            |[1001, 1002]|null                |
+--------------------+------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: What's the rough estimate of your input file's size? This 4 keys only? And what's your Spark version?

Comment: it contains around 50 keys, it is around 25 mb size file , we are using spark 3.2.0 version @qaziqarta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `spark.read.json` method expects json file to be in a [json-lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format. But your input file doesn't contain any records and the resulting dataframe will end up being just one row with as many columns as there are keys in the file.

On the other hand, the file is fairly small and doesn't have complicated format, so I think it would be simpler to just read the file, process it to conform to your desired structure, and pass it to `spark.createDataFrame`:

```py
import json

measurements = []
with open("test.json") as f:
    if (js := json.load(f)):
        measurements = [dict(v, measurement=k) for k,v in js.items()]
df = spark.createDataFrame(measurements).select("measurement", "ACCOUNT", "KEY_FIGURE")
+--------------------+------------+--------------------+
|         measurement|     ACCOUNT|          KEY_FIGURE|
+--------------------+------------+--------------------+
|            Premiums|[1001, 1002]|                null|
|              Claims|[2001, 2002]|                null|
|Expenses Acquisition|[3001, 3002]|[3400530, 910050505]|
|    Expenses Run-Off|[3001, 3002]|[3400535, 910100505]|
+--------------------+------------+--------------------+
```